# Standard Libraries are not recognized on RED (RobotFW 4.0)

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I have a problem after making an update to run Robot Framework 4.0 with Python 3.7.9.

My OS is RedHat 7, I install a new RED, lates Robot (4.0) and the latest Python (3.7.9).

Everything was fine except when I launch [RED](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-robot-editor) (Eclipse RED - Robot Editor), Standard Libraries seems to not be recognized. On the Project explorer they appear:

```
BuiltIn (0)
Collections (0)
...
XML (0)
```

The strange thing is, when I right click on them to display the source code, RED open the source code correctly (but it does not work the documentation).

And Obviously my tests doesn't work, saying keyword from these libraries are not found.
During the installation I added the good paths to my bashrc so I don't think that the problem is here.
Does someone know what could be the problem?

Comment: https://forum.robotframework.org/t/red-doesnt-find-builtin-libraries-with-robotframework-4-0b1/1100

Answer (score 1):

RED does not support robotframework 4. See issue: https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/413